# Duplicate DIV with input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Basically I've managed to become stuck yet again trying to duplicate a DIV and it's form elements using jQuery.

Button:

```
<div class="addNew" id="addSkill">Add Skill <i class="icon-plus"></i></div>
```

Div and contents I wish to duplicate

```
<div class="row" id="skiller">
    <div class="label">Skill</div>
    <div class="input"><input class="lineput" placeholder="Doing stuff."></div>
</div>
```

I've tried using the clone method, I just can't seem to create a functioning line of code that will duplicate it beneath the first div, and make it ready for PHP multiple data entry.

Thanks!

Comment: you just want to clone an element and put it somewhere else?

Comment: Basically yeah! I've tried the most obvious, but it seems I'm doing something wrong. This always happens 4 in the morning when I'm starting to lose my marbles.

Comment: I want to clone the entire #skiller DIV. And put it bellow the existing one.

Comment: doesn't cloning an element with an id not work? As far as I can remember id's have to be unique... >.> Or am I missing something?

Comment: See this is what I thought.. Can anybody tell me a way I can successfully clone that div, with it's input field content and label?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would be a start:

```
$("#addSkill").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var new_skiller = $("#skiller").clone();
    new_skiller.attr("id", "skiller-"+$(".row").length);
    new_skiller.insertAfter(".row:last");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and then [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the item inside a div like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="thing">
<div class="row" id="skiller">
    <div class="label">Skill</div>
    <div class="input"><input class="lineput" placeholder="Doing stuff."></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="addNew" id="addSkill">Add Skill <i class="icon-plus"></i></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#addSkill').click(function(){
        var thing = $('#skiller').clone();      

        $('.thing').append(thing);
    });

});
```

View the [jsFiddle Demo....](http://jsfiddle.net/xxc7Y/)

*Note: you'll need to give them seperate names/make it an array to access*

Answer (score 0):

Try this. should work. Note: ID can not be duplicated. the following code will duplicate div with id as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addSkill').click(function(e) {
        var skiller = $('#skiller').clone();
        $( "#skiller" ).after( skiller );
    });
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/XpN95/